# CLOB IS VERY SLOW

Tags: database, oracle, clob

i send e-mail with attachment on DB ORACLE. I form this attachment that but it's very very slow

```
FOR x IN (select *
from l_sulkk
where PROJECT_ID = proj_id)
    LOOP
        v_clob :=
               v_clob
            || x.CONTRACT_NUMBER
            || ';'
            || TO_CHAR(x.PERSON_ID)
            || ';'
            || x.BEHAV_MODEL
            || ';'
            || TO_CHAR(x.BEHAV_MODEL#DATE_CALC, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
            || ';'
            || TO_CHAR(x.DATE_INSERT, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
            || ';'
            || TO_CHAR(x.DONE_DATE, 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
            || ';'
            || x.ERROR_MSG
            || ';'
            || TO_CHAR(x.PHONES_ID)
            || ';'
            || x.PHONES_NUM
            || ';'
            || TO_CHAR(x.INFORMER_PK)
            || ';'
            || TO_CHAR(x.CLIENT_TIME_ZONE)
            || ';'
            || x.CITIES_KID_FACT*/
            || UTL_TCP.crlf;

    END LOOP;
```

There is any variants how to optimize this process?

Comment: Just because you *can* do something with a particular technology doesn't mean you *should*. This looks like a job for an application/scripting language - I wouldn't use a stored procedure.

Comment: Question has been resolved! Remade request and got rid of clob. Use lines pass with varchar.

Comment: User says he got a solution somewhere else.

Comment: @user3043884 you should post what you found as an answer and "accept" it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **VARCHAR2 buffer** to get chunks of data up to 32k, then use 
`dbms_lob.writeappend` to form the CLOB.

Additionally you can do some pre-concatenating in the SQL itself (just don't use pl/sql functions like UTL_TCP.crlf there.

Thats the general idea.
You can also [check this post](http://www.talkapex.com/2009/06/how-to-quickly-append-varchar2-to-clob.html), to get some test results.